# ANTLR4 TypeScript target can't find modules nor properties?

Tags: typescript, parsing, antlr4, grammar

Alright, I'm at my wits end with this problem. I'm trying to use TypeScript with ANTLR4, and no matter what I do, I can't figure out what the issue is (there's not much documentation on the TS target for ANTLR...). I'm not sure if the error is in my package.json, tsconfig.json, or what. I keep getting errors `cannot find module antlr4ts`, and other errors like `Property 'exitRule' does not exist on type...`. I'm so confused and any help would be absolutely appreciated.

I've tried following the [GitHub](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4ts) page, effectively using their exact steps, but it breaks as soon as I get to this step.

My grammar is simple enough where `r()` is the starting parser rule. The lexer/parser files are stored in the main directory (after running antlr4ts). Even though I get an `/output/` directory with some js files, I've tried to minimize my project to the essentials (even without an `index.html`; just `tsconfig.json, package.json,`, the grammar, and the grammar generated files).

One of the errors:

```
Cannot find module 'antlr4ts'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "output",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
  },
  "include": ["./*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "naturaldeductionthesistypescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "antlr4ts": "antlr4ts -listener MyGrammar.g4",
    "compile-typescript": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "antlr4ts": "^0.5.0-alpha.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "antlr4ts-cli": "^0.5.0-alpha.4",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { ANTLRInputStream, CommonTokenStream } from 'antlr4ts';
import { MyGrammarLexer } from 'MyGrammarLexer';
import { MyGrammarParser } from 'MyGrammarParser';

// Create the lexer and parser
let inputStream = new ANTLRInputStream("text");
let lexer = new MyGrammarLexer(inputStream);
let tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
let parser = new MyGrammarParser(tokenStream);

// Parse the input, where `compilationUnit` is whatever entry point you defined
let tree = parser.r();
```

Grammar

```
grammar MyGrammar;
r   : 'hello' ID;
ID  : [a-z]+ ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I keep having many problems.

Comment: @BBacon unfortunately, I just gave up and used JS with ANTLR. It wasn’t worth the hassle to get it to work with TS. Such a shame that the architecture is so complicated to get up and running.

Comment: Hey @joshua-crotts https://github.com/DaveJacksonKC/antlr4ts-monaco-demo this demo helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange that you have so many problems with that. I have used the TS runtime in several projects of mine and never saw anything like that. As a working example check this out: [antlr4-c3](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4-c3).

You can see the config files there and how I use the runtime. For completeness here the config files:

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts", "test/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

Example code from my unit tests:

```js
...

    import {
        ANTLRErrorListener, CharStreams, CommonToken, CommonTokenStream, RecognitionException, Recognizer, Token,
    } from "antlr4ts";
    import { Override } from "antlr4ts/Decorators";
    import { TerminalNode } from "antlr4ts/tree/TerminalNode";

...

            const inputStream = CharStreams.fromString("var c = a + b");
            const lexer = new ExprLexer(inputStream);
            const tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);

            const parser = new ExprParser(tokenStream);
            const errorListener = new ErrorListener();
            parser.addErrorListener(errorListener);
            parser.expression();
            expect(errorListener.errorCount, "Test 1").equals(0);
```